# Spring data - paging - get page number of item

Tags: spring-data, paging

I use a paging in my application.
This is my code:

```
final Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, this.getHistoryPageSize(), new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "date"));
    final List<History> pagedHistory = historyRepository.findPagedHistoryByTenantAndDateBetween(tenant, start, end, pageable);
```

My question now would be if there is a possibility to get the page number of an item so that I can show this page.

Answer (score 1):

Use method `getPageNumber()` of `Pageable`:

```java
int pageNumber = pageable.getPageNumber();
```

Example:

```java
@GetMapping("/")
public String users(
        @RequestParam(value = "q", required = false) String query,
        Model model,
        @PageableDefault(size = PAGE_SIZE, sort = SORT, direction = ASC) Pageable pageable
) {
    Page<User> users = repo.findByNameAndEmail((query != null) ? query : "", pageable);
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    model.addAttribute("query", query);

    model.addAttribute("totalPages", users.getTotalPages());
    model.addAttribute("current", pageable.getPageNumber());
    model.addAttribute("previous", pageable.previousOrFirst().getPageNumber());
    model.addAttribute("next", pageable.next().getPageNumber());

    return "users";
}
```

[source code](https://github.com/Cepr0/crud-sb-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/cepr0/RootController.java)